# Can I crop an excel chart to remove part of the chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, crop

I followed some instructions to create a speedometer chart (pie chart with a scatter line chart on top).

However, this solution leaves a large blank space below the chart; 50% of the chart's space is taken up by a blank pie slice to make the chart take up the normal semi-circular speedometer shape.

I have dragged the plot area handles out as far as they go in the chart area, but I can't drag them outside of the chart area to make it bigger.

Attempts to resize the chart area will automatically scale the chart down so it doesn't crop.

Is there a way to crop a chart in excel, so that some of it is simply gone, rather than rendered white and taking up space? Solutions relying on cropping a screenshot are undesirable as a screenshot won't update when the data source changes.

See attached picture for example.

Edit: I can't seem to upload the chart. Here is a link: http://www.keithtwombley.com/speedochart.png

[image: chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the bottom Data Point with no fill, and the Chart Area with no fill. Use textboxes to contain the area you like, and provide the title.
This sample is not the same graph but shows the idea
[image]

Comment: Are you adding a text box behind the chart, to make it look cropped? Setting the fills to No Fill won't allow me to resize the chart without scaling.

Comment: Yes, sorry yo not be clearer. That is exactly what was done. it is not actually cropping the chart, just making the background of it, and the one section transparent, and then wrapping it all in a textbox behind. The 'Financial Health' was textbox as well. Not what you asked for in terms of cropping, but what might work